# read JSON, POSTed to my visualforce Site page from 3rd party. without authentication

Tags: visualforce, json, post

The currentPage().getParameters() can read GET pagams, and also reads POST body only if the header Content-Type = **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

However, when the Content-Type changes to **application/json**, I cannot read incoming JSON, nothing in the keySet().
Here is the code I use to read

```
Map<string, string> requestText = (Map<string, string>)ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
```

The external application uses **application/json** in header and there is no way to influence that. Also, no way to do Oauth with that app.

I'm grateful for your ideas

Comment: Are you aiming to build a headless API that is exposed to the unauthenticated internet?

Comment: I want the webhook of KanbanFlow.com to update records on salesforce. i haven't completely figured out their security yet.. out of my depth to be honest.. now i am not certain what the kanban server sends (above observations were tested through POSTman, as I was unable to read any data from the server, my class does register the request, but that's it - no body) I'll do a bit more reading.. just wanted some pointers..

Comment: Security - From KanbanFlow interface doc

_Each webhook has an associated secret you can use to verify that the request came from KanbanFlow. The request made to your URL endpoint will contain a special header called X-KanbanFlow-Signature. The signature is a HMAC-SHA256 hex digest of the payload using the secret as the key. Exactly how to verify the signature depends on your platform_ . You can code this verification into your Apex class with @RestResource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce does not support reading other types of payloads. Instead, you can write an Apex class that uses @RestResource, then expose that class by adding it to the Guest profile for your Site. See [Quick Tip – Public RESTful Web Services on Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html) for more information on how this works.

Comment: and i was hoping it's going to be as easy as reading GET params.. Thanks, I'll give it a read. Still early days of rest, finding my footing.. If it's too complicated, I may just make an intermediate json server to convert JSON to url params, as i only need 2 values.

Comment: @VladimirMironov It's really easy, just a few lines of code. The blog post has everything you need, and it's only about a five minute read or so.

Comment: It worked! Beautiful JSON in the end. Thank you Brian!